# Let X be the sine of the randomly chosen angle of the interval $(-\pi / 2, \pi / 2)$. Find the density function and the distribution function of X.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X be the sine of the randomly chosen angle of the interval $(-\pi / 2, \pi / 2)$.
Find the density function and the distribution function of X.

I got a little trouble visualating what happens in the distribution function. I know that clearly doesnt look like the sine function at $(-\pi / 2, \pi / 2)$ but has something to to with it.

Answer (score 0):

We are interested to find $F(z)=P(\sin(X)\le z)$. It's not hard to see that $F(z)=0$ if $z\le-1$ and $F(z)=1$ if $z \ge1$.

Let $-1<z<1$. Then 
$$F(z)=P(\sin(X)\le z)=P(X\le\arcsin(z))=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\arcsin(z)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

where the last equality comes from the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.